# Blank leaflet-js map (with both gem helper and native code)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, rubygems, leaflet

I am trying to display a leaflet-js map on a rails view on my application.

First, I tried to use the [leaflet-rails gem](https://github.com/axyjo/leaflet-rails). I followed all the instructions but it didn't work.

Then, I went on and followed the [leaflet-js quick start quide](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html) instructions but it didn't work either.

What I am getting in both cases is the page below ***(notice how the map on the right is "blank")***:

[image]

Here is my code:

***someplace.html.erb***

```
<div id="map" class="large-5 columns">
    <!--<img src="http://placehold.it/600x300&text=map" />-->
</div>
<%= map(:container_id => "map", 
        :center => { :latlng => [51.52238797921441, -0.08366235665359283],
        :zoom => 18 } ) %>
```

***someplace.js.coffee***

```
map = L.map("map").setView([51.505, -0.09], 13)
L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/myapikeyhere/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            attribution: "Map data &copy; <a href=\"http://openstreetmap.org\">OpenStreetMap</a> 
            contributors, <a href=\"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA</a>, 
            Imagery © <a href=\"http://cloudmade.com\">CloudMade</a>"
            maxZoom: 18).addTo map
```

***leaflet.rb***

```
Leaflet.tile_layer = "http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/myapikeyhere/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
Leaflet.attribution = "Your attribution statement"
Leaflet.max_zoom = 18
```

I am totally clueless as to what I am not doing properly so any hints would greatly help!

Comment: Did you add any code to the initializers? There should be (at least) a Leaflet.tile_layer in there somewhere. Additionally, you should include a Leaflet.attribution

Comment: Yes, I have a `leaflet.rb` file. (updated the question, thanks the comment)

Comment: Have you substituted in your API key in leaflet.rb as well?

Comment: Yes, "myapikeyhere" is actually my cloudmade API key. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you replaced "API-key" in the url by your API key ?

Comment: Unbelievable! The javascript solution works now - however the helper still resists. If nobody gives a more complete answer until Monday morning I am going to accept yours, thanks a lot for pointing this out!

Comment: Will a different tile dealio work as well: http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png ?